# Array Printf issue

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working on simple program that is supposed to list the numeric values in an array; a certain way. This is how I would like to have the output look like:

```
Printing Array:
 1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20
21   22
```

It has to be lined as seen above and line must only contain 10 numbers.
I seem to have everything formatted correctly but my output doesn't look like that.

Here is what I am getting:

```
Printing Array:
 1
 2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10    11
12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19    20    21
22
```

I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong but here's my code:

```
//disregard the name 'Juice', I like to give my programs weird names

public class Juice 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
      //sets up the array
      int[] numbers = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22};

      //title
      System.out.println("Printing Array: ");

      //counting the elements
      for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
          {
              //prints each element value with 4 spaces in between
              System.out.printf("%4d", numbers[i]);

              //once line reaches ten values; print new line
              if (i % 10 == 0)
              {
                System.out.printf("\n");
              }
          }
   }
}
```

Comment: Very sorry, this is my first question posted.

Comment: You skipped `3` and `11`. Why did you even write that array? Why not just loop from 1 to 22 in the `for` loop?

Comment: Sorry about that. Not sure why I didn't use a loop. Kept it basic.

Comment: Don't just change your output! In your array, you forgot to include the numbers `3` and `11`, causing those numbers to not appear in your output. Don't edit your question to fix the bug; it creates a moving target for answerers and risks making valid answers look wrong. Definitely don't change the output to something the posted code doesn't produce.

Comment: Hmm... the revision log doesn't match my memory, and I'm not sure whether it's due to edits in the grace period or not paying enough attention. Whatever the case, I should go to bed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if ((i+1) % 10 == 0)
 {
    System.out.printf("\n");
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code does what you asked it to.

On first loop, `i=0`, but `i % 10 == 0` is also true, so it prints new line.
You can use many different approaches to fix this, but probably easiest one will be to replace this condition to `(i+1) % 10 == 0` or to `i % 10 == 9`.

Answer (score 1):

you almost did it

```
public class Juice 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
      //sets up the array
      int[] numbers = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,11,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32};

      //title
      System.out.println("Printing Array: ");

      //counting the elements
      for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
          {
              //prints each element value with 4 spaces in between
              System.out.printf("%4d", numbers[i]);

              //once line reaches ten values; print new line
              if (i % 10 == 9)
              {
                System.out.printf("\n");
              }
          }
   }
}
```

i've modified a conditions to `if (i % 10 == 9)`

**OUTPUT**

```
Printing Array: 
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20
  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30
  31  32
```

Comment: `i != 0` is not required.

Comment: oops, sorry, small leftover :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to avoid the confusion between the index to the array element and the element count switch to using a foreach loop.

```
   //counting the elements
    int i = 1;
    for (int number : numbers) {
      //prints each element value with 4 spaces in between
      System.out.printf("%4d", number);

      //once line reaches ten values; print new line
      if (i % 10 == 0) {
        System.out.println();
      }

      i++;
    }
```